# wp query error while paging the posts

Tags: wp-query, pagination

i am new to wordpress and i am learning paging the posts but the code below isnt working and i cant find whats wrong. please help.

**the code:**

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2&paged='.$paged );
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
<h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; Previous' ); ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link( 'More &raquo;' ); ?></div>
</div>

<?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
?>
```

**the error**

> Call to a member function get() on null in
>   /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/query.php on line 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `null` to `$wp_query` then querying `get_query_var( 'paged' )` this is expected that you will get this error!

First query `get_query_var( 'paged' )` then set the original `$wp_query` to `null`

Example:-

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

global $wp_query;
$temp = $wp_query;

$wp_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2&paged='.$paged );

while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link( '&laquo; Previous' ); ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link( 'More &raquo;' ); ?></div>
</div><?php

wp_reset_postdata();

$wp_query = $temp;
```

> NOTE: Do not forgot to add `wp_reset_postdata()` after loop.